# Can't Access apache webserver outside Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webserver

I want to access my website outside Ubuntu but it not work I can access the website inside عbuntu and every thing fine I executed this command

```
sudo netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN
```

and I have this result

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17400       1012/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29406       936/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      123        19686       942/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          29408       936/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          66907       6103/apache2
```

and this some content of apache2.conf file

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: It does listen on the ipv6 protocol, you're trying to reach it from your local ipv4 network though right?

Comment: yes I am trying to access it from another computer in local network

Comment: Maybe you should edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Could you [edit] the question with its?

Comment: check that the ufw didn't block apache??